# Is the text book wrong about delimiter usage

Tags: java, delimiter

On page 66 of [An Introduction to Object-Oriented Programming with Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073523305), C Thomas Wu
introduces a delimiter.  To my understanding by default it divides string up using whitespace.

So to divide the string into tokens via the return button, the example uses:

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
   scanner.useDelimiter(lineSeparator);
```

which to me is get the value of return from the system, assign it to lineSeparator and the tell scanner to use lineSeparator as the delimiter.

The problem is when I copy it word for word, I get an error.

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;


class Ch2Sample1 {
    public static void main(String [] args){
      
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    Scanner.useDelimiter(lineSeparator);
    
    String quote;
    System.out.println("enter last name");
    quote = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(quote);
    
    
}}
```

[image]

Have I made a mistake, or has the book made an error?

Comment: You used a capital. Replace `Scanner.useDelimiter` by `scanner.useDelimiter`.

Comment: change Scanner to scanner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use a instance method off of the type as if it were a static method.  Change `Scanner.useDelimiter(lineSeparator);` to `scanner.useDelimiter(lineSeparator);`.

Comment: damn that a silly mistake. much appreciated guys